# How to group objects from Illustrator Layer menu?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, selections

How do you select and group multiple layers swiftly in Illustrator? Obviously you can tick them one by one and group after that but I am looking way for grouping layers selected between two shift + click's in the menu.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not entirely certain what you mean by "group layers". You can group *objects* but you can't *group* layers.

**Collect in New Layer** from the `Layers Panel` menu will combine highlighted layers in the Layers panel to a single layer with sub-layers.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple Pressing the CTRL key click on the layers you want to group and then press CTRL+G. I hope this is the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new layer and then Ctrl-select and drag the layers you want grouped onto the new layer.

Answer (score 0):

The [command](/questions/tagged/command) key only highlights the object on the Layers Panel. It serves a different purpose. Dragging and rearranging for example.

In order to group elements, each one must be selected, not just highlighted.

To select an object in the Layer panel, you can use the [option](/questions/tagged/option) Key (Mac users).

To group multiple objects you can use

[shift](/questions/tagged/shift) + [option](/questions/tagged/option) + click

Once you are done selecting, you may proceed to group with

[command](/questions/tagged/command) + G

ps. I don't believe it is possible to select a range of objects.  However, you can highlight them and drag inside an existing group.

Answer (score 0):

I was also hoping to be able to group layers, which is a great feature available in Photoshop. Apparently, it's not possible in AI, likely because what appears as a single layer is already actually a group of layers (which you can reveal by clicking the arrow just to the left of the layer name).

Answer (score -1):

Select the laters you need on the screen(not in layers listing), and press CMD+G(Mac)

Comment: question is about grouping layers not just objects

Comment: I managed to group layers with the following approach in AI 2015 on my Mac 10.11